# Investigating the Impact of Additive Gaussian Noise on EEG Signal Classification: Analyzing the Relationship between Augmented and Original Data

Tags: time-series, classification, white-noise, data-augmentation

**Definition:** I have conducted research on EEG signal classification, specifically focusing on distinguishing between two different classes using raw EEG signals. Data availability poses a significant challenge in the EEG domain, which necessitates the implementation of data augmentation techniques. In my case, I have applied additive Gaussian noise with zero mean and varying standard deviations (σ∈{0.1,0.01,0.001}) to the raw EEG signals for data augmentation. Additionally, I have considered the magnification factor (m∈{1,2,3}) for the additive noise. By augmenting my training data using different combinations of m and σ, I have observed an improvement in test set accuracy in most cases.

**Question**: Considering the training data as X_train, the augmented data as X_train_aug, and the test data as X_test, I would like to determine if there exists a mathematical relationship between (X_train, X_test) and (X_train_aug, X_test) that can explain the observed improvement. Are there any criteria available for measuring the relationship between these variables that can help elucidate the results?

Thanks in advance.